# How to remove device from pool

Tags: solaris, zfs

I did a mistake when I added a new device in my raidz pool thinking ZFS should do it automatically.

```
 :~# zpool status
  pool: data
 state: ONLINE

 scan: resilvered 78,3G in 2h4m with 0 errors on Tue May 10 18:12:31 2016
config:

    NAME         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    data         ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz2-0   ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t2d0   ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t3d0   ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t4d0   ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t5d0   ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t6d0   ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t7d0   ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t8d0   ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t9d0   ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t10d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t11d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
      c2t13d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
    spares
      c2t12d0    AVAIL   
      c2t14d0    AVAIL
```

I'm thinking c2t13d0 is not in the raidz pool, is it?
How to remove it form the data pool ?

Thank for any help.

Comment: To go along with the two answers below (back up, destroy pool, create new pool, restore), you should be aware that ZFS cannot add disks to a raidz group. The only way to make a ZFS pool have more capacity is by adding new toplevel vdevs. You may want to consider two raidz2 toplevels instead of a single giant one.

Comment: As has been pointed out, you cannot remove a vdev from a pool. I suspect that, but don't know if, you can use file-backed pools on OpenSolaris. If you can, that's a good way to set up a test environment where you can try things out without risk of problems. (I suspect you also had to use `-f` to force the vdev add operation, which should have been all the warning needed...)

Comment: @mmusante you can also replace all the drives in a vdev with larger drives, one by one.  When they've **all** been replaced, the extra capacity will become available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.  It's now in the pool as a single-drive vdev.  vdevs can not be removed from a pool.

That's the bad news.

The worse news is that you've now effectively got a RAID-0 with your `raidz2-0` vdev and the `c2t13d0` vdev.  This is NOT good. It's doubleplusungood.

Your options are:

- to live with the pool you have created
- backup, destroy and re-create the pool, and restore.

Neither option is good.  backup/recreate/restore is the **right** option in the long run, but requires significant downtime (the only way to avoid that is to create a SECOND pool of the same size or larger and `zfs send` to that).

---

BTW, one thing can do to fix the lack of redundancy is to attach a mirror to the `c2t13d0` vdev.  Maybe use one of the spares if they're the same size.

Use something like:

```
zpool attach data c2t13d0 anotherdisk
```

It's far from ideal but a RAIDZ2 vdev striped with a mirror vdev has redundancy (still an abomination but not one that's going to eat your data), while RAIDZ2 striped with a single-drive doesn't have any reliable redundancy (some of your data will be ONLY on the single-drive vdev.  This will invariably turn out to be your most valuable and irreplaceable data).

It does make the first option ("live with it") suck a lot less...at least for now.  In the long run, you'll want to rebuild your pool.

I don't have access to the Solaris man page, but here's a relevant extract from the ZFS On Linux version of the `zpool` man page (bolding added by me for emphasis).  Solaris version should be the same or very similar:

> `zpool attach [-f] [-o property=value] pool device new_device`
>
> Attaches  new_device  to  an  existing  zpool  device. **The existing device cannot be part of a raidz configuration**. If  device  is  not currently  part  of  a mirrored configuration, device automatically transforms into a two-way  mirror  of  device  and  new_device.  If device  is part of a two-way mirror, attaching new_device creates a three-way mirror, and so on. In either case, new_device  begins  to resilver immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, your pool comprises of two vdevs, the disk c2t13d0 and raidz2-0, which are striped.

Unfortunately ZFS doesn't (yet) offer a possibility to remove a vdev from a pool. So your only option is to destroy the pool, recreate it and restore from backup.

Comment: This is possible in 2023 (and at least 2 years ago). You can remove single-drive and mirrored vdevs. You still cannot remove RAID-Z.